# How to Make a SSL URL Prefix

Tags: html, ssl, web

I've tried Goggling this, but I can't really come up with a technical string to search on. I want to get my site to have that green box that appears with SSL sites. For example, on Bank of America's site (in Chrome):

[image: Chrome snapshot]

I don't know whether this is a HTML trick, a server operation, etc. Really have no idea and don't know a good way to search for "that green box thing". Does anyone know how sites do this?

Comment: Did you ever try to click on "that green box thing" and see what it has to tell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [**this**](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95617), "If a site uses an Extended Validation SSL (EV-SSL) certificate, the organization's name also appears next to the icon in green text. Make sure the browser is set to check for server certification revocation to identify sites with EV-SSL certificates."

And:

If you still don't see the organization's name, it may be due to one of the following conditions:

- The website might not use an EV-SSL certificate. EV certificates
  provide extra assurance as to the identity of the website, but not
  all websites using SSL use EV-SSL certificates.
- The website might contain security errors, such as mixed content or
  expired certificates.
- The certificate revocation information may be temporarily unavailable
  from the server.

You can read more about Extended Validation SSL certificates [**here**](https://www.symantec.com/theme.jsp?themeid=how-ssl-works&tabID=2&inid=vrsn_symc_ssl_FAQ) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate).

Comment: +1. Thanks. Won't let me mark as the answer for 8 minutes. But I will when I can.

Answer (score 1):

You "simply" serve the page using [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Socket_Layer), and make sure that all static resources on the page from other domains (images, CSS, JavaScript, etc.) are also served over HTTPS. Otherwise, visitors to your site will see [scary-looking security warnings](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95617) about "insecure resources on the page" (particularly scary/intrusive in IE).

You'll need an [EV-SSL certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate).

Answer (score 0):

This is called an [Extended Validation Certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate). They cost quite a bit more than standard SSL certs.